# iOS 10: NSInvalidLayoutConstraintException: Constraint improperly relates anchors of incompatible types

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, ios10

After updating to iOS 10 Im getting this error a bunch on one  of my apps

> NSInvalidLayoutConstraintException: Constraint improperly relates
>   anchors of incompatible types:

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170495270 UIView:0x1010e1d90.top == AppName.OtherView:0x1010dc6f0.centerX (active)>
```

I've never had an issue using a constraint like this before and I'm only getting it on my iOS 10 devices. Any ideas?

Comment: What are the two anchors in the constraint?

Comment: same problem here. Have you found the problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You perhaps are doing something like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: viewA, attribute:
                .leading , relatedBy: .equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20)
```

So you do not stitch the correct anchors together like `.leading` and `.top`. In this case it must be `.leading` and `.leading`.

Interestingly this wasn't a problem with iOS9.

Comment: That was totally the issue. I had a Top - CenterX instead of a Top - .CenterY. what I don't understand, is why did this start crashing on iOS 10? It should have crashed on iOS 9, and did apple warn anyone that this change would be a breaking change upon iOS 10 release? Is there a list somewhere where apple publishes breaking changes you need to update prior to an OS release? I saw a BUNCH of apps go nuts when I upgraded to iOS 10 in terms of layout.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Reset to suggested constraints, 
it will fix missing constraints [image]