# Thread 1: signal SIGBART on AppDelegate class

Tags: ios, swift

I started getting this error after I recently updated iOS. I think it has to do with the formatting of my constraints but I could not figure it out. 
This is my error message

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidLayoutConstraintException', reason: 'Constraint improperly relates anchors of incompatible types: '

This is some of my constraint code

```
// Bottom constraint: description
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint (item: descriptionTextView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: itemImageView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    //right constraint: description
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: descriptionTextView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: itemImageView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 160))

    //left constraint: description
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: descriptionTextView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal , toItem: itemImageView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))

    //height constraint: description
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: descriptionTextView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0, constant: 100))
```

How do I solve the Thread 1: signal SIGBART crash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 10 NSInvalidLayoutConstraintException: Constraint improperly relates anchors of incompatible types:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532700/ios-10-nsinvalidlayoutconstraintexception-constraint-improperly-relates-anchors)

Answer (score 0):

In the last addConstraint : toItem: self -> self.view

```
addConstraint( NSLayoutConstraint(item: descriptionTextView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal , toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, multiplier: 0, constant: 100))
```